# Recursive buy x get y

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm trying to setup a rule that gives a free product every 5 buyed.
This work if I add 5 products to the cart --> grand total is correctly reduced

But if I add 10 or more products the total amount of cat is reduced only by the price of 1 product.

Answer (score 1):

I tried doing this myself and found it just wouldn't work - I could get close but there was always something not quite right, e.g. Buy 5 get 1 free, buy 6 and suddenly you get 2 free and so on.

In the end I found an extension to do it. The one that worked for me was [Buy X Get The Cheapest Free by Zero1](http://shop.zero1.co.uk/buy-x-get-cheapest-free.html), but I imagine there are a few to choose from. Search [Magento Connect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/) or even just search in Google.